# C# sql query stop at cmd.execute

Tags: c#, sql, ado

Hello I've made a method that takes search parameters and then returns a query. This was done using ADO.net now what I have noticed is that my method abruptly ends on the cmd.execute. Here is my method.

```
  public class SQLStringSearchService
    {
        string connectionString = string




        public async Task<List<TransactionJournal>> SearchArchivedTransactionJournal(DateTime transactionDate, string Region, string MCC, string MerchantID, string TxnCurrency, string TerminalID, decimal TxnAmount, string BIN, string MsgType, string MaskedPan, string ProcessingCode, string ClearPan, string ResponseCode, string AuthorizationCode, string EntryMode, [FromQuery] PaginationDTO pagination)
        {
            var monthString = string.Empty;

            if (transactionDate.Month < 10)
            {
              monthString = transactionDate.Month.ToString().Insert(0,"0");
            }
            else
            {
                monthString = transactionDate.Month.ToString();
            }
            var DbTable = "TRANSACTIONJOURNAL_" + transactionDate.Year.ToString() + monthString;
            var queryable = new List<TransactionJournal>();

         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Table = @Table Where TransactionDateTime <= @DateTime and AcquirerID = @Region and MerchantCategoryCode = @MCC and MerchantID = @MerchantId and Currency = @TxnCurrency and TerminalID = @TerminalId and " +
                        "TransactionAmount = @TxnAmount and Bin = @Bin and MessageType = @MsgType and ProcessingCode = @ProcessingCode and PANM = @Panm and PAN = @Pan and ResponseCode = @ResponseCode and AuthorizationCode = @AuthCode and ResponseCode = @ResponseCode";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Table", DbTable);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", transactionDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region", Region);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCC", MCC);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MerchantId", MerchantID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxnCurrency", TxnCurrency);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TerminalId", TerminalID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxnAmount", TxnAmount);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bin", BIN);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MsgType", MsgType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessingCode", ProcessingCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Panm", MaskedPan);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pan", ClearPan);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseCode", ResponseCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthCode", AuthorizationCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseCode", ResponseCode);
                    queryable = (List<TransactionJournal>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
            var orderedQuery = queryable.OrderByDescending(x=> x.TransactionDateTime).AsQueryable();
            await HttpContextExtensions.GetPage<TransactionJournal>(orderedQuery, pagination.Page, pagination.QuantityPerPage);
            return await orderedQuery.Paginate(pagination).ToListAsync();

        }

    }
```

I have tried debugging and the method just ends, I can't seem to figure out what the problem could be. If someone could show me an example of maybe the correct way to so this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server does not support anything like `SELECT * FROM TABLE = @Table`...

Comment: Show us the code that calls this method.  Is it within a `try catch` block?

Answer (score 0):

Code doesn't just stop but any time it seems like it does, it's probably encountering an exception that isn't handled properly, inside of a coding construct that cannot tolerate it - I most often see this if there is some background threading involved, the thread hits an exception, it's stopped and the exception is transferred to whatever was managing the thread (which then does nothing with it). The thread just goes away and VS stops tracking it. You might find it switches to another thread but it does look like the code "just stopped"- probably we'd find that this method was called without await or its in a backgrounder worker that doesn't retrieve the exception

All in, this code has some flaws and cannot work. As per the comments the sql is invalid. You also wouldn't/couldn't executeScalar and hope to get a list out of it. By definition  scalar is a single value, the top left cell of any result set- there's no scope for it to be a list of values. If you want a list you have to executeReader and fill the list ...

If you enable break when thrown (go in the debug menu , look for exceptions window, put a tick next to Common Language Runtime - now as soon as any exception is raised, handled or not, the code will stop. You'll probably find now that your code is stopping on a sql exception, but at least you can fix it and move on. It's recommend you at least wrap your executeXxx in a try catch...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an invalid query. You can't pass table as a variable the way you're trying to. To achieve that type of functionality you have to use `string.Fromat`.

Try something like:

```cs
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Join(
        string.Fromat("SELECT * FROM {0} ",DbTable),
        "WHERE TransactionDateTime <= @DateTime ",
        "AND AcquirerID = @Region ",
        "AND MerchantCategoryCode = @MCC",
        "AND MerchantID = @MerchantId ",
        "AND Currency = @TxnCurrency ",
        "AND TerminalID = @TerminalId ",
        "AND TransactionAmount = @TxnAmount ",
        "AND Bin = @Bin ",
        "AND MessageType = @MsgType ",
        "AND ProcessingCode = @ProcessingCode ",
        "AND PANM = @Panm ",
        "AND PAN = @Pan ",
        "AND ResponseCode = @ResponseCode ",
        "AND AuthorizationCode = @AuthCode ",
        "AND ResponseCode = @ResponseCode");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", transactionDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region", Region);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCC", MCC);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MerchantId", MerchantID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxnCurrency", TxnCurrency);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TerminalId", TerminalID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxnAmount", TxnAmount);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bin", BIN);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MsgType", MsgType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessingCode", ProcessingCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Panm", MaskedPan);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pan", ClearPan);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseCode", ResponseCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthCode", AuthorizationCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseCode", ResponseCode);
    queryable = (List<TransactionJournal>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

You don't have to use the `string.Join` the way I did. I just wanted to split the query in parts to make it a bit more readable for me. You can format that all sorts of ways.

When possible, I would recommend that you write your queries and test them in SQL server or local instance. Then you can use it to create your command text string.

Something like this might have helped you spot the issue:

```sql
DECLARE @Table varchar(50) = 'TRANSACTIONJOURNAL_202003',
        @DateTime datetime = GETDATE(),
-- ... And so on with the rest of the variables you need
-- you have lots of variables
-- you get the gist


SELECT * FROM  Table = @Table
WHERE TransactionDateTime <= @DateTime
AND AcquirerID = @Region
AND MerchantCategoryCode = @MCC
AND MerchantID = @MerchantId
AND Currency = @TxnCurrency
AND TerminalID = @TerminalId
AND TransactionAmount = @TxnAmount
AND Bin = @Bin
AND MessageType = @MsgType
AND ProcessingCode = @ProcessingCode
AND PANM = @Panm
AND PAN = @Pan
AND ResponseCode = @ResponseCode
AND AuthorizationCode = @AuthCode
AND ResponseCode = @ResponseCode;
```

One more thing. I would recommend not using `SELECT *`. Instead I'd explicitly write out the column names. If they ever add another column to that table it could break things. Specially if they change the order of the columns.

Hope this helps.